Flutter Icon Launcher package cause the phone to lock unexpectedly and also failed to load the icon image
I’m trying to change the icon on my flutter app by using flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.14.1, I configured it on pubspec.yml and ran “dart run flutter_launcher_icons” command to create the new launcher icon, it ran smoothly and showed the success message.
The problem occurs when I am running the app on real device, in real device the app caused phone to lock and screen went black, when I turned on the phone and unlocked it the app is fully loaded.
Before using the package, running the app has no problems at all.
I tried searching online and did not find any documentation explaining the problem, even chatgpt could not help.
Here is my pubspec.yml code
description: “xxxxxxxxxx”
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.3

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  #qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
  #qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.3.2
  path: ^1.9.0
  file_picker: ^8.1.2
  audioplayers: ^6.1.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.9.0
  location: ^5.0.0
  geocoding: ^3.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.14.1

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: “launcher_icon”
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  remove_alpha_ios: true
#  web:
#    generate: true
#    image_path: "path/to/image.png"
#    background_color: "#hexcode"
#    theme_color: "#hexcode"
#  windows:
#    generate: true
#    image_path: "path/to/image.png"
#    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
#  macos:
#    generate: true
#    image_path: "path/to/image.png"

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/to/resolution-aware-images

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/to/asset-from-package

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/to/font-from-package```

Please help! thanks in advance.


Exact same case here. Undid all changes and the app started working again, so I'm confident the issue is whatever the icon lib did.

Its the same case for me brother !
but find a solution quicky here :
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/595
